# Amazon DynamoDB NoSuchMethodError Exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, credentials

Been trying to insert some entries to Amazon DynamoDB,
I get an error on these lines of code:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(SimpleDBLoadData.class
    .getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties"));

dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
```

This is the `Exception`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.auth.QueryStringSigner: method <init>()V not found
```

Any ideas?
Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: It looks like a problem with crypto classes. Are you using Oracle Java or something else?

Comment: Seems like missing classes in aws SDK. Remove sdk libraries and re add will help.